# Clever way of calculating and storing cumulative rainfall for each polygon of a MULTIPOLYGON sf-object

Tags: r, sf, list

What I have is this `sf`-object:

```
Simple feature collection with 50 features and 8 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 611398.7 ymin: 5122699 xmax: 745144.8 ymax: 5207956
CRS:            +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
First 10 features:
   20171225 20171226 20171227 20171228 20171229 20171230 20171231 20180101                       geometry
1         0      0.0    0.600        0        0        0        0 0.600000 POLYGON ((675867.9 5138308,...
2         0      0.0    0.900        0        0        0        0 1.600000 POLYGON ((671435.1 5122705,...
3         0      0.2    0.000        0        0        0        0 1.600000 POLYGON ((688357.4 5152557,...
4         0      0.7    0.000        0        0        0        0 0.900000 POLYGON ((698123.5 5169814,...
5         0      0.0    0.000        0        0        0        0 0.800000 POLYGON ((672429.8 5197674,...
6         0      0.7    0.000        0        0        0        0 0.900000 POLYGON ((698977.7 5168984,...
7         0      0.0    0.000        0        0        0        0 0.500000 POLYGON ((717004.7 5196926,...
8         0      0.0    0.000        0        0        0        0 3.116667 POLYGON ((622728.9 5152046,...
9         0      0.8    0.025        0        0        0        0 0.900000 POLYGON ((695677.5 5172000,...
10        0      0.9    0.300        0        0        0        0 0.600000 POLYGON ((704247.9 5184909,...
```

Where each column (minus the geometry-column) is a date, and each row is a polygon. The cells are mean rainfall values for that day and polygon. Now I'd like to calculate the cumulative rainfall for each day and polygon and store that in a clean way in some R-object. Up to now I just worked with spatial objects that either were just one point or one polygon. There I could simply do something like:

```
# get the geometry column
    geom = df %>% st_geometry()

    df_long = df %>%
      st_drop_geometry() %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to="dates", values_to="precip") %>%
      mutate(dates = as.Date(dates, "%Y%m%d")) %>%
      # get the cumulative count for the days
      mutate(accumulated = cumsum(precip)) %>%
      mutate(geom = geom) %>%
      st_as_sf()
```

to get something simple like this:

```
  dates      precip accumulated
* <date>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2017-12-25  0           0    
2 2017-12-26  0           0    
3 2017-12-27  0.600       0.600
4 2017-12-28  0           0.600
5 2017-12-29  0           0.600
6 2017-12-30  0           0.600
7 2017-12-31  0           0.600
8 2018-01-01  0.600       1.20
```

However, when I have a spatial object of multiple points or polygons, things get quite messy in my head. I could maybe split the `sf`-object into `nrow(df)`-`sf`-objects and apply the same operation and store them in a list. But I don't feel like this is the best way to go. Maybe someone has some kind of idea on how to approach this:)